# Confusing letter

Tags: pattern, no-computers, letters

I once received a letter where all letters of the alphabet was shuffled around.

The task was then to find out what each letter was and then read the letter.

I wrote a little letter for you:

> Be qnbp qfuq izz zfqqflp nisf affe lfjzidfg av iehqnfl hef. Die vhr gfdhgf qnbp qfuq? Be qnbp zfqqfl izz hx qnf izjniafqp zfqqflp ilf ehq rpfg, ph qniq tbzz yiof bq fipbfl xhl vhr qh gfdhgf bq. B nhjf qniq vhr tbzz fechv gfdhgbem qnbp zfqqfl, b tbzz ehq yiof bq qhh zhem qnhrmn, pbedf qniq tbzz af fipbfl xhl vhr qh gfdhgf bq.

Now your task is to translate that letter and give a list of all the letters eg A = XXX, B = XXX etc.

Good luck!

Comment: In the future you might want to add the [no computers] tag to this type of puzzle as https://quipqiup.com/ can solve it pretty trivially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A=I B=A C=D D=G E=F F=X G=M H=I I=B J=C K=O L=Z M=Y N=E O=H P=J R=L
>  S=P T=Q U=R V=S W=T X=U Y=V
>  And the text says
>  "In this text all letters have been replaced by another one. Can you 
>  decode this text? In this letter all of the alphabets letters are not 
>  used, so that will make it easier for you to decode it. I hope that 
>  you will enjoy decoding this letter, i will not make it too long though, 
>  since that will be easier for you to decode it."

Comment: Where is the Q and Z?

Comment: @Scratch---Cat Refer to the decoded text's third sentence.

Comment: Did you use a computer to decide the letter?

Comment: @Jdrupal Did it by hand, with Notepad.

Comment: Congratulations :)